# How to make bend transition effect with pixelbender

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel-bender

http://www.designlicks.com/
http://www.group94.com/

in first site after loading complete there is a transition that bending all page.
i saw this effect before some other sites but i cant find any example.
i am sure it is built with pixelbender.
Can you help me with that or send me some links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ["Slide Wring"](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=2394033) filter in the Pixel Bender Exchange.